# ResourceHttpRequestHandler: Resource not found, DispatcherServlet: No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to do a simple Spring app which gets all the entries inside a table calls "creditcards".

This is the folder organization:

[image]

CreditCardsManagerApplication.java:

```
package com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CreditCardsManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CreditCardsManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

CreditCard.java:

```
package com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="creditcards")
public class CreditCard {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String creditcardnumber;
    private String owner;

    public CreditCardDTO toDTO(){
        return new CreditCardDTO(this.creditcardnumber,this.owner);
    }
}
```

CreditCardDTO.java:

```
package com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards;

public class CreditCardDTO{
    private String creditCardNumber;
    private String owner;

    public CreditCardDTO(String creditCardNumber, String owner){
        this.creditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

CreditCardRepository.java:

```
package com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CreditCardRepository extends JpaRepository<CreditCard, Integer> {

}
```

CreditCardService.java:

```
package com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards;

import java.util.List;

public interface CreditCardService {

    public List<CreditCardDTO> getAll();
}
```

CreditCardServiceImpl.java:

```
package com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CreditCardServiceImpl implements CreditCardService{
    private CreditCardRepository creditCardRepository;

    @Override
    public List<CreditCardDTO> getAll() {
        List<CreditCardDTO> l = new LinkedList<CreditCardDTO>();
        for (CreditCard cr: this.creditCardRepository.findAll()) {
            l.add(cr.toDTO());
        }
        System.out.println(l.toString());
        return l;
    }
}
```

CreditCardcontroller.java:

```
package com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class CreditCardController {
    private CreditCardService creditCardService;

    @GetMapping("/creditcardslist/")
    public List<CreditCardDTO> getAll(){
        return this.creditCardService.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test(){
        return "Hello World";    // THIS WORKS
    }
}
```

If I go to localhost:8080/ it works and it displays "Hello World", but if I go to localhost:8080/creditcardslist, it says:
[image]

and in the trace-logging-level console it displays:

```
2023-06-28T22:55:10.153+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /creditcardslist
2023-06-28T22:55:10.153+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2023-06-28T22:55:10.153+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2023-06-28T22:55:10.153+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning instance
2023-06-28T22:55:10.153+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@75462fa7
2023-06-28T22:55:10.153+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2023-06-28T22:55:10.154+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/creditcardslist", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-28T22:55:10.154+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 4 interceptors
2023-06-28T22:55:10.154+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .i.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl : Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Opened Session [e30f86c1-e4f4-4874-ac25-242dda4c2ab2] at timestamp: 1687985710155
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Closing session [e30f86c1-e4f4-4874-ac25-242dda4c2ab2]
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@7b81df7f]
2023-06-28T22:55:10.155+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2023-06-28T22:55:10.156+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Closing logical connection
2023-06-28T22:55:10.156+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Logical connection closed
2023-06-28T22:55:10.156+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={masked}
2023-06-28T22:55:10.156+02:00 TRACE 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@75462fa7
2023-06-28T22:55:10.156+02:00 DEBUG 1683317 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
etc etc
```

and these are the logs when I go to localhost:8080/ and it correctly displays "Hello World":

```
2023-06-28T22:23:30.281+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-28T22:23:30.293+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'creditCardController'
2023-06-28T22:23:30.294+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards.CreditCardController#test()
2023-06-28T22:23:30.296+02:00 DEBUG 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-06-28T22:23:30.296+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .i.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl : Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null
2023-06-28T22:23:30.296+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Opened Session [66de72e4-de4f-4e42-8402-61252358db48] at timestamp: 1687983810296
2023-06-28T22:23:30.309+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Arguments: []
2023-06-28T22:23:30.336+02:00 DEBUG 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/html', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
2023-06-28T22:23:30.337+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["Hello World"]
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 DEBUG 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Closing session [66de72e4-de4f-4e42-8402-61252358db48]
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@5f7b4697]
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Closing logical connection
2023-06-28T22:23:30.345+02:00 TRACE 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Logical connection closed
2023-06-28T22:23:30.346+02:00 DEBUG 1663300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
etc etc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your endpoint ending with a slash     `@GetMapping("/creditcardslist/")`

Can you change it to `/creditcardslist`?

Kind regards.

Comment: I can't believe it..... now at least it goes on but at a certain point there's error: 

`2023-06-29T00:26:09.715+02:00 TRACE 1738794 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards.CreditCardService.getAll()" because "this.creditCardService" is null
 at com.progetto.creditcardsmanagerApp.creditcards.CreditCardController.getAll(CreditCardController.java:14) ~[classes/:na]`

Comment: you need to autowire your credit card service to your controller. Not recommending field injection but may you add @  Autowired like -> @ Autowired private CreditCardService creditCardService;

Comment: you will also need for  @Autowired   private CreditCardRepository creditCardRepository; in your class

Comment: Actually, to fix, I found out that I had to add the constructor lol inside CreditCardServiceImpl and CreditCardController. And also needed to add getter and setter inside CreditCardDTO

Comment: yes it is also recommended, with that way you are using constructor injection. Directly using in field making field injection